# Increase badge size on Mac dock

Tags: macos, dock

Is there anyway to increase the size of the badges (like the unread mail count) on the Dock? I want the badge to basically occlude more of the icon (Without increasing the size of the parent icon)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No.

The dock badging style is not changeable by the user, and also (I believe) not changeable by the application unless it extends the dock badge.

One option would be to keep the dock size small but put a large magnification on it so you can simply flick your mouse down to the Mail icon and it will magnify enough to read the badge.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's a general way to do it, but [DocStar](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/dockstar/) customizes the dock badges on the Mail icon. There's options to resize the badge, add different badge shapes, and create different badges with different criteria.

Comment: Ah, I wanted to change my mail badge, but not in the actual Mail app (since I am using Postbox instead of Mail) - but DocStar did do exactly what I wanted, just wrong program :(